# Cordova - File Download not working

Tags: android, cordova, steroids

I am facing issues to download images with phonegap + steroids

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
    var downloadUrl = "http://www.gajotres.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png";
    var imageName = "logo_radni.png";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

        fileTransfer.download(
            downloadUrl,
            fileSystem.root.toURL() + "/" + imageName,
            function (entry) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
    });
```

The error is this

> {"code":3,"source":"http://www.gajotres.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png","target":"file:///storage/emulated/0//logoradni.png","http_status":401,"body":null,"exception":null}

Error 3 is

> 3 = FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR

I am on wifi

```
navigator.connection.type = "wifi"
```

In my config.xml as far as I concern is included

```
<access origin=".*" />
```

Comment: is the permission mentioned in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: @DanielGatti suggest you to have a look at this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: @Beelphegor my problem was i have "config.android.xml" on www. I delete it, and work like a charm